# URL href in comments didn't work this once

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

[Recording Skype conference calls on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/189333/recording-skype-conference-calls-on-osx/189339#189339)

Why the link on **my comment** on the above link wasn't highlighted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Specifically the last sentence of:

> ### How can I format and link in comments?
>
> Comments can be [formatted with a subset of Markdown](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/): **bold** (`**bold**`), *italic* (`_italic_` or `*italic*`), ***bold italic*** (`***bold italic***` or `___bold italic___`) and `code` (`` `code` ``) are allowed.
>
> URLs will be automatically converted into actual links. Links are also allowed by using the Markdown syntax `[link text](http://myurl)`. **However, the two methods [cannot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70382/in-a-comment-markdown-inexplicably-failed-to-turn-so-urls-into-links/70421#70421) be combined in a single comment.**

Comment: Weird restriction, but fair enough! Thanks!